# How to draw a circle with an array of pixels?

Tags: java, pixel, 2d-games

So I'm currently making a 2d game with java and the image the player sees on the screen is displayed as an array of pixels where the first pixel in the array is displayed at location (0,0) on the screen

The index location of any one pixel in the array, given the (x,y) coordinates, is equal to:

```
  (x + (y * width)),  where width is the width of the open game window.
```

So, to change the color of a pixel, I'm using this code:

```
  pixels[x+y*width] = color;
```

I am attempting to draw a circle using the equation for a circle where (h,k) is the center of the circle:

```
  (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2,     r is the radius.
```

Currently, using this equation, I'm getting a sort of unfinished circle where the top left corner is missing somehow. Here's my code and a picture of the output:

```
    for (xp = h-r; xp < h+r; xp++) {
        yp = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow((xp-h), 2))+k;

        pixels[xp+yp*this.width] = color;
    }

    for (int yi = k-r; yi < k+r; yi++) {
        yp = yi;

        xp = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow((yp-k), 2))+h;

        pixels[xp+yp*this.width] = color;
    }
```

[--->> Unfinished Circle Pic.<<---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNeME.png)

I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I found a solution, but it's not as robust as I'd like it to be, so if you have any suggestions, they are welcome. Here's my code for the solution:

Comment: okay well it's not letting me put my solution, oh well...